# "Notification from Department for Work and Pensions" in tax rebate claim - UK

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, annuity, rebate

My wife stopped working in November 2014, and consequently we suspect she may have overpaid tax, and be able to reclaim from HMRC.

We've found the relevant form to fill in ([here](https://public-online.hmrc.gov.uk/lc/content/xfaforms/profiles/forms.html?contentRoot=repository:///Applications/PersonalTax_iForms/1.0/P50&template=P50.xdp), linked from [this HMRC page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/income-tax-claiming-tax-back-when-you-have-stopped-working-p50)). All good.

On one of the later pages we found:

`How we will make your repayment?
Please send either your P45 (Parts 2 and 3) from your pension/annuity payer, or notification from Department for Work and Pensions, as well as any P45 (Parts 2 and 3) sent to you by an employer.`

We have the P45 from the (ex-)employer, and she has no pension/annuity, so we can't possibly need to provide that.
But I have no idea what `notification from Department for Work and Pensions` is, whether we need to provide one, and how we acquire one if we do.

Anyone know what this is / means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect they just want to know about any benefit or state pension payments she might have received, and they don't mean that you definitely would have anything, even though the wording does imply that you should have either that or a P45 from a pension provider.

As I mentioned in [my other answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/48362/366), given that the tax year has now finished, the procedure for reclaiming tax ought to be a lot simpler than it is during the tax year. I suspect it will be a lot simpler to follow the procedure on [this page](https://www.gov.uk/claim-tax-refund/too-much-tax-taken-from-your-pay) instead of filling in the P50 form. That one seems to be much more tailored to in-year refunds.